# how to apply ie10 hack ul li element's wrong display for the css code

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10

I have a problem in css ie10 hack.

Good view is this. ( on IE11 )

[Good view on IE11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXpYZ.png)

Bad view is this. ( IE10 and under )

[Good view on IE10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDpwh.png)

the CSS code is

> .util {float:right; margin:0 auto; border:0px solid red; margin-top:60px;}
>
> .util ul li {float:left;}

and HTML code is

```
<div class="util">
                    <ul>
                            <li><a href="/login.php"><img src="/img/new/snb_01.png"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="/register.php"><img src="/img/new/snb_02.png"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="/subpage.php?p=m36"><img src="/img/new/snb_03.png"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="/board.php?bo_table=m31"><img src="/img/new/snb_04.png"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="/board.php?bo_table=m72"><img src="/img/new/snb_06.png"></a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
```

I've been tried to look for the solution on searching web.
And I added the code,

```
.util li {display:inline;}
```

But didn't work..

please let me know, how to apply it to ie10-hack and display correctly.

Comment: Try to add `display:block` to `.util`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding `display: inline-block` to `.util`. If this does not resolve the issue you could even wrap the `<ul>` in a `<table>` element. A good example of this can be found on CSS tricks link - [centering list items horiztonally](https://css-tricks.com/centering-list-items-horizontally-slightly-trickier-than-you-might-think/#article-header-id-0)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should always avoid Browser Hacks for following reasons:

1. CSS validation may not be possible
2. Your CSS becomes more complex
3. Your CSS may not be future-proofed
4. There is rarely a need for them

More info [Why avoid CSS Browser Hack](https://www.sitepoint.com/5-reasons-to-avoid-css-hacks-and-conditional-stylesheets/)

Even though if you want Hack then [Browser hacks](http://browserhacks.com/) has all the hacks required by all browsers.

For IE10 :

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
 // Your CSS
}
```